# disable elastic scrolling (the rubber band effect) on ios

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am trying to make my website more flexible and universal for all devices. However, I have encountered a problem while trying to adapt it for IOS, which is elastic scrolling or rubber band effect (when you scroll until the end of website and you are still able to scroll it, so you can see hidden content under it). I have looked up for solution in numerous sources, but none of them helped me to solve the problem effectively (`overflow: hidden;` in the body disables all scrolling functions of the webpage). I want to solve the problem using html/css or pure JavaScript (No Jquery or other libraries). Here is my [webpage](http://aufaprojects.ml/public/pages/home/home.html)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I can't see the issue on IPhone4s. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: I have tried the way offered in the answer below, but it is not a satisfying solution.

Comment: Now the problem is there again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above solution, having a container that is fixed is a good solution. But sometimes this might be hard to apply if you don't have access to the top of the HTML hierarchy.

So you can disable the move action if the user tries to scroll top of the website with JS, something like;

```
var startY = 0;
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    startY = e.touches[0].screenY;
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    var amountMovedY = e.touches[0].screenY - startY;
    if (amountMovedY > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  // Disable move action when movement amount is negative (user tries to positive to top!)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `fixed` property to a container div, so it will not be scrollable, and then make content in the container scrollable (e.g give scrollable to an article and put the article in fixed container). This is NOT the best solution for the problem, though it was the one that worked for me.